# App Engine Launcher: 502 / Connection Refused on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Sorry if I am posting a duplicate, but I have searched for a solution:

I am writing my first GAE app with Python on Windows 7 and am following the Getting Started Hello World example found at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld

When I try access the application, I get a `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)` in the browser. The accompanying log file is shown below.

Does the App Engine Launcher try to connect to the internet when running the app? I am behind a firewall/proxy, so could that have anything to do with it?

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 249, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 89, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 225, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 320, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 398, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 511, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 436, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 370, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Connection refused
```

Comment: The development server checks for updates when starting so you could try running it with `dev_appserver --skip-sdk-update-check True yourapp/` and see if the error goes away

Comment: its local as in localhost (not internet) - it could be something to do with Microsoft, personally I feel Linux is a better choice for development

Comment: @dlebech Thanks, tried that, but that is not the problem.

Comment: @peterretief I would also prefer Linux, but I don't have that option here ATM.

Comment: I don't use MS but i do remember there are tons of meaningless permissions you have to set or unset, Google would be your friend there I would imagine

Comment: @mydoghasworms Ok too bad. By the way, I am developing an app on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu and have no problems in either OS so I do not think it is fair to blame Microsoft :-) If you want a Linux-like setup on Windows, I highly recommend [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full+installer+official+git). I wrote a [short blog post](http://thoughtflow.dk/2013/04/25/unix-tools-on-windows/) about it earlier this year.